# Character Array Conversion to 2D integer array Failure

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, character

I seem to have trouble converting a character array to a 2D integer array. The specifics are as follows:

I want to convert a character array that contains a specific delimiter to a multidimensional array in which the end of each row is specified by the delimiter found inside the character array ( I have already made sure in a different method that every row has the same length).

The array contains only 0s and 1s.

The problem is that when testing the method it appears that it (the method) skips a row - reads the first row, the next row is 0s, reads the third row, the  fourth is 0s.

These are the methods (the method in question and the testing method):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converts a character array to 2D int array, where each character is a digit and only the digits of 1 and 0 are 
    /// allowed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The 2D int array.</returns>
    /// <param name="charArray">Character array.</param>
    /// <param name="delimiter">Delimiter.</param>
    public int[,] ConvertCharArrayTo2DIntArray(char[] charArray, char delimiter){
        int columnCounter = 0;
        //count how many rows
        while (charArray [columnCounter] != delimiter) {
            columnCounter++;
        }

        //count how many lines taking into account the delimiter
        int rows = charArray.Length/(columnCounter+1);

        int[,] twoDimArray = new int[rows, columnCounter];

        //count
        int h = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columnCounter; j++) {
                if (charArray [h] != '\n') {
                    twoDimArray [i, j] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(charArray [h]);
                    //throw exception if the array contains numbers other than 1 or 0
                    if (twoDimArray [i, j] != 1 && twoDimArray [i, j] != 0)
                        throw new ArgumentException ();
                    h++;
                } else {
                    h++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return twoDimArray;
    }
```

This is the testing method:

```
    [Test()]
    public void TestConvertCharArrayTo2DIntArray(){
        HelperClass hc = new HelperClass ();
        int[,] twoDimArrayExpected = new int[,]{ 
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 } };
        char[] charArray = new char[] {'0','1','0','1','1','\n','1','1','1','1','1','\n','0','1','1','1','0','\n','0','1','0','1','0','\n'};
        int[,] twoDimArrayActual = hc.ConvertCharArrayTo2DIntArray (charArray, '\n');
        for (int i = 0; i < twoDimArrayExpected.GetLength (0); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < twoDimArrayExpected.GetLength (1); j++) {
                Console.Write (twoDimArrayActual [i,j]);
                //Commented out because it throws exceptions                                 
                //Assert.AreEqual(twoDimArrayExpected[i,j],
                //twoDimArrayActual[i,j]);
                if (j == twoDimArrayExpected.GetLength (1) - 1) {
                    Console.Write ("\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The output is this:

01011

00000

11111

00000

I may simply be stuck, but right now I really  can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the inner loop ends, you are positioned on the delimiter. This is the point where you need to skip the character delimiter incrementing the control variable `h`

As you do now, you increment the control variable but then you break out of the inner loop. Just removing the break instructon however doesn't work because exiting the inner loop increments the control variable `i`of the outer loop leaving every even row empty and unprocessed

You could try to fix your code with

```
int h = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < columnCounter; j++)
    {
        twoDimArray[i, j] = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(charArray[h]);
        //throw exception if the array contains numbers other than 1 or 0
        if (twoDimArray[i, j] != 1 && twoDimArray[i, j] != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException();
        h++;
    }
    h++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Real easy if you use a list object

```
 List<List<int>> twoDimArrayExpected = new List<List<int>>() { 
               new List<int>() { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
               new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
               new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 },
               new List<int>(){ 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 } };

            string resutls = string.Join("\n", twoDimArrayExpected.Select(x => string.Join("", x)));​
```